# Why I see a line at the top of the first page?

Tags: koma-script, hebrew, scrbook

When I'm writing a book using KOMA-Script usung class `scrbook` with package `fancyhdr`, I get a weird line at the top of the first page:

[image]

Here is MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
  \fancyhf{} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{3pt} 
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lhead{AAA}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\bigskip{}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont{\textbf{אבג}}
\par\end{center}

\bigskip{}


\part{אבג}

\chapter{אאאא}

\section{בבבב}

אאא

בבב

\section{אבג}
\end{document}
```

No matter how I change the code -- I can't control this line.

Do you know how can I remove it?

Comment: Comment line 10 `\pagestyle{fancy}`?

Comment: The log says `Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrbook)              I'd suggest to use …..

Comment: @AboAmmar are you able to follow up comment with answer as that does seem to be at root of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your code are some issues:

1. Because I do not know hebrew and the specific problems with I simply deleted the usage of hebrew and hebrew font in your given code.
2. The usual way to define a titlepage in `scrbook` is to use command `\maketitle` (I added in the following mwe) or to define a titlepage with environment `titlepage`.
3. `fancyhdr` with `scrbook` can result in problems, better would be to use `scrlayer-scrpage`.
4. Your issue results from the using of this total unusual code printing the titlepage:

   ```
   \bigskip{}

   \begin{center}
   \fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont{\textbf{titel}}
   \par\end{center}

   \bigskip{}
   ```

   That code results that `fancyhdr` adds an headrule because your then working `\pagestyle{fancy}` added in your preamble added the headrule you do not want. To get rid of that you have to add

   ```
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   ```

   after `\begin{document}` **or much better use `\maketitle` or environment `titlepage`**.

In the following mwe without hebrew fonts I used first your wrong way printing the title and added afterward the correct usage of `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[%
  a4paper,oneside,english,
% hebrew,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[%
  unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
  bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
  breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  linkcolor=blue
}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
  \fancyhf{} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{3pt} 
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lhead{AAA}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================
\bigskip{}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont{\textbf{titel}}
\par\end{center}

\bigskip{}


\title{this is the title}
\author{john doe}
\maketitle % <==========================================================


\part{part}

\chapter{chapter}

\section{sectiona}

\blindtext

\section{sectionb}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting titlepages]

Comment: The only thing that works (at the real example, not at the MWE) is `\thispagestyle{empty} ` - so you solve it for me with this simple code, but maybe for other uses the - I'll use the other part of the solution :-)